# Tomcat9 org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init ignores custom DataSource

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat9

I am using an Spring bean to set a JDBC pool connection to a mySql server. This includes setting a custom DataSource to set my own password encryption.

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

public class CustomDataSource extends DataSource {
    
    public void setPassword(String encodedPassword){
        Crypt crypt = new Crypt();
        String decodePassword = crypt.decryptValue(encodedPassword);
        getPoolProperties().setPassword(decodePassword);
    }

}
```

The bean is configured this way:

```
   <bean id="MySQLSource" class="com.mypackage.CustomDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;serverTimezone=GMT"/>
        <property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
        <property name="password" value="E5EDF4AE2517F5F69417CF9496FCC6ED065F6542003956B2BDDA6CFD" />

        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />

        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="15" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />

        <property name="validationQuery" value="Select 1" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000" />
    </bean>
```

This configuration works in Tomcat8 in servers with Ubuntu 18.6 and 20.4. Also works in Tomcat8 and Tomcat9 on Eclipse on a MacOS laptop which I use for testing. These use OpenJDK9.

However, I have another server with Ubuntu 20.4 with Tomcat9 using OpenJDK11 and in this case this setup does not work. It shows the error:

```
03-Oct-2021 22:39:26.892 WARNING [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
03-Oct-2021 22:39:27.145 SEVERE [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'silkbuilder'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
```

However, when I set a non-encrypted password in the bean's configuration it works as it should be:

```
<property name="password" value="no-encrypted-password" />
```

So, in this case it seems like the bean is ignoring "com.mypackage.CustomDataSource" and is using "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" directly.

I have also modify the CustomeDataSource to display the unencrypted password in the catalina log:

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

public class CustomDataSource extends DataSource {
    
    public void setPassword(String encodedPassword){
        Crypt crypt = new Crypt();
        String decodePassword = crypt.decryptValue(encodedPassword);
        System.out.println("pwd:"++decodePassword); //<--This is new
        getPoolProperties().setPassword(decodePassword);
    }

}
```

In the other servers I can see the password in the catalina log as it should be. However in the Ubuntu 20.4 with Tomcat9 it does not show the password in the catalina log.

I could set the server with a plain password and ignore the issue. But I want to have this server with an encrypted db password as the rest.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom class overriddes the `setPassword` method, but contains only half of the operations of the original method:

```java
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.poolProperties.setPassword(password);
        this.poolProperties.getDbProperties().setProperty("password",this.poolProperties.getPassword());
    }
```

When overriding methods you should always consider calling the overridden method, by using the keyword `super`:

```java
    @Override
    public void setPassword(String encodedPassword){
        Crypt crypt = new Crypt();
        String decodePassword = crypt.decryptValue(encodedPassword);
        super.setPassword(decodePassword);
    }
```

Comment: Adding the other operations helped. Thanks Piotr!